# Why does my Event Hub exponential retry policy not continue forever?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

I expect the following code to retry *forever*, but it consistently throws an exception after ~40 seconds of being disconnected from the network -- which is the best I can do to simulate transient Internet connection or Event Hub outages.

```
var eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(…);
eventHubClient.RetryPolicy = new RetryExponential(
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), // minBackoff
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), // maxBackoff
    Int32.MaxValue); // maxRetryCount
…
eventHubClient.SendAsync(…).Wait();
```

What's going on here?

I'm using the `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` NuGet package, version 4.1.10 on .NET Framework 4.6. I'm willing to change either package or framework if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48183719/287610) put me on the right track. It turns out that, buried inside the class hierarchy for `EventHubClient`, there's a reference to the Service Bus package's `MessagingFactory` -- which has *its own per-operation timeout that is not exposed through the `EventHubClient` type*.

So the way to set up a client with a very long timeout would be something like this:

```
var builder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString)
{
    OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(30), // TimeSpan.MaxValue is not allowed
    TransportType = TransportType.Amqp // This needs to be set; default is NetMessaging
};
var messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(builder.ToString());
var eventHubClient = messagingFactory.CreateEventHubClient(entityPath);
eventHubClient.RetryPolicy = new RetryExponential(
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
    Int32.MaxValue);
```

**That being said,** after verifying that this works I realized that in my scenario it's actually important to send telemetry during the retries, so I actually went back to the default retry policy on `EventHubClient` and just wrapped the `SendAsync(…)` call with a separate retry policy using [the Polly library](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) that allows me to send telemetry before each retry.